# How to solve this same routing pattern issue in asp.mvc routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm practicing MVC routing and now I'm stuck in a situation which I don't understand how to solve. I have two controllers and action in both controllers and two routes in RouteConfig class. Here:

RouteConfig

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Students",
        url: "{Class}/{Students}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Class", action = "Students" });

        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "SubjectDetail",
        url: "{Class}/{Subject}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Subject", action = "SubjectDetail"});
```

Now the problem is when I go to the class/Students url it works fine but in case of class/subject it again redirects me to the class/Students url. I know there is some route pattern mistakes. How to solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: `but in case of class/subject it again redirects me to the class/Students` -- That's because both of your routes have the same signature.  How is the routing engine supposed to differentiate between a student and a subject, if both URLs look the same?

Comment: That's why i ask. How can i differentiate?. How can I use same pattern for different controllers?

Comment: Your urls are exactly the same even though the template variables ({Students}, {Subject}) have different names. For example if you call cs101/bob, there is no way to know whether bob is a student or a subject. Since the Students route is defined first, it uses it.

Comment: You should add something to the route to differentiate it use {Class}/Students/{Name} and {Class}/Subject/{Title} , for example.

Comment: Yeah I think this could work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Students",
        url: "classes/{classId}/students/{studentId}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Class", action = "Students" });

        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "SubjectDetail",
        url: "classes/{classId}/subjects/{subjectId}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Subject", action = "SubjectDetail"});
```